# Windows Store apps won't open after changing permissions on Windowsapps folder

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I was trying to access the windowsapps folder and to do so I had to change the permissions. Once I had got into the folder I changed nothing, but now none of the apps from the Windows Store, or the Windows Store app itself, will open. They simply display the splash screen for a moment and close. I have tried running sfc /scannow multiple times, chkdsk /r, and even refreshing windows. (which as I understood it should reset all the settings, but while all the permissions seem to have been reset the apps still won't open.) Help?

Comment: What permission did you change  and what permission do you have now ?

Comment: Do you have UAC disabled by chance?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I honestly can't remember which ones I changed specifically, but I remember I definitely changed the Owner to everyone. That seems to have been reset though, (as have all the other settings) and I only added permissions, so I didn't think it would affect anything. Here's what I have currently: http://imgur.com/uoPTA1x 

And yes I did have UAC enabled, but I probably bypassed it... it's karma for messing with files I shouldn't have, but I'm hoping not to have to clean install the entire OS.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "i probably bypassed UAC"

Comment: As in, I probably disabled it briefly to do what I was trying to do, then turned it back on again. Probably not my smartest of ideas...